# Magical test for convergence of improper integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I found [this](http://thesai.org/Downloads/Volume2No11/Paper%2021-%20A%20New%20Test%20Method%20on%20the%20Convergence%20and%20Divergence%20for%20Infinite%20Integral.pdf) article while surfing the web. I hope it's not some kind of joke, because if it is it really fooled me. I'm trying to figure out the proof of theorem 2.3

I don't understand how the author went from $\lim_{x \to \infty}xR(x) > 1$ to:

$$\forall k>0, \space xR(x) \ge k+1$$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The article is not from the most solid of venues, it seems -- a pay-to-publish journal with an impressive-at-first-sight but suspiciously broad title. And their [call-for-papers](http://thesai.org/Publications/CallForPaper?code=IJACSA) says that paper submissions will be refereed in **two weeks** and accepted ones published **one month** after submissions. That doesn't really inspire confidence in the results ...

Comment: Maybe interesting: The Crackpot Index (http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/crackpot.html).

Answer (score 2):

Is false: $R(x)=2/x$ verifies
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}xR(x)=2>1$$
but
$$\forall k: 2=xR(x)> k+1$$
is false.

EDIT:

Barely understandable phrases: "But it is difficult or impossible to find the comparison infinite." "It is well-known that the convergence and divergence of
infinite integral for the different integrand which its limit is zero is different."

Weird expressions: "incredibly similar".

Wrong application of L'Hôpital in the proof of Theorem 2.1.

...

Comment: What about the article itself? Is it wrong?

Comment: I will read it tomorrow.